# Match a string starting with : character, but not starting with \:

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I need a RegEx to replace a word in a long string starting with a single `:`, but not starting with `\:`.

Match: `:Amazing`

No match: `\:Amazing`

I tried `[^\\](:Amazing)`, but it also matches `x:Amazing`

I want to replace string `Hello, this is :Amazing and also \:Amazing`

with `Hello, this is COOL and also :Amazing`

Thank you.

Comment: So you only need `(?<!\S):Amazing`? Demo https://regex101.com/r/dc7iL9/1

Comment: You're welcome. I added an answer for both PHP and JS.

Answer (score 1):

You are telling that you don't need any character after `:`. You need a negative look-behind for this:

```
:(?<!\S.)Amazing
```

- `\S` means a non-whitespace character

*Note: This works in PHP PCRE*

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/dc7iL9/2)

JavaScript doesn't support lookbehinds (only Google Chrome as of now). To have it in JS too you need something like this:

```js
var str = `Hello, this is :Amazing and also \\:Amazing x:Amazing`;
console.log(str.replace(/(^|\s):Amazing/g, "$1COOL"));
```

Comment: Why didn't you write it like you did in your comment?  It takes fewer steps that way.  Is there a fringe case that I am not considering?

Comment: @mickmackusa When you use a literal character or a known starting point in a regex, there will be some optimizations done before executing matching process in PCRE. This leads into a faster failure or success. You don't want to rely on regex101 steps. What do you see when you click on *regex debugger* at the left for both regexes?

Comment: Never clicked that before.  Ugh, how annoying -- I've been relying on the step count forever.  I don't like how the debugger takes me away from my pattern-writing interface.  Now I wish they would offer the debugger counts where the step count is.  ...and for that matter, I've never clicked the code generator either.